# Update Earliest created Contact On Account

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a scenario where Account is related to contacts through lookup relationship.
I have a field on Account called Account_Start__c(Date) and a field on Contact called Contact_Start__c(Date). Now i want to populate earliest Contact_Start__c on Account_Start__c field on Account object. I tried below trigger but it is not working for me. Can anyone help me with this?

```
trigger EarlyDateOnAccount on Contact (after insert,after update) {
    set<Id> acntset = new set<Id>();
    List<Account> lstcon = new List<Account>();
    for(contact c : trigger.new)
    {
        if(c.AccountId != NULL)
        {
            acntset.add(c.AccountId);
        }
    }
    List<Account> lstacnt = [Select Id, Name, Account_Start__c,(Select Id, LastName, Start_Date__c ORDER BY Start_Date__c Desc Limit 1 From Contacts) 
                             From Account where Id IN : acntset];
    for(Account a : lstacnt)
    {
        List<Contact> ct = acc.contacts;
        acc.Account_Start__c = ct.add(Start_Date__c);
        lstcon.add(acc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please **[edit]** your post to be more specific than *"it is not working"*?

Answer (score 1):

There's a far easier way to do this: an aggregate query. Here's what that would look like:

```
trigger EarlyDateOnAccount on Contact (after insert,after update) {
    Account[] updates = new Account[0];
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
        accountIds.add(record.AccountId);
    }
    accountIds.remove(null); // Avoid private contacts
    for(AggregateResult result: [
        SELECT MIN(Contact_Start__c) startDate, AccountId accId 
        FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds GROUP BY AccountId]) {
            updates.add(new Account(Id=(Id)result.get('accId'), Account_Start__c=(Date)result.get('startDate')));
        }
    update updates;
}
```

This is a pretty standard "aggregate query update" pattern that is often used in code. We aggregate the data to query on (AccountId), query the database, then perform an update.

---

As to your code specifically:

```
    acc.Account_Start__c = ct.add(Start_Date__c);
```

Should have been:

```
    acc.Account_Start__c = acc.Contacts[0].Contact_Start__c;
```

This would have copied the value over for you. At this point, you still forgot to update the records at the end of your loop:

```
update lstcon;
```

Always remember to commit your changes when you query records and plan on updating them.

Finally, your ORDER BY ... DESC is incorrect; this would have given you the *latest* record, not the *earliest*. When speaking about time in programming terms, ascending means forward in time, and descending means backwards in time.